# failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: apache-2.2

early this morning there was a log rotation, the last line in the apache error log was:

```
 [error] (9)Bad file descriptor: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)    apache2: Syntax error on line 250 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
```

Apache failed to auto reload after this. When I got around to looking at this an hour or so later, i simply did an apache restart and everything was fine. It did leave a warning in the new log file:

```
[warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

What does this mean, and how can I correct what ever went wrong?

(Apache/2.2.22 (Debian))

**edit**
or if this is not something that can be fixed, is there a way of getting apache to auto reload x qty of times before giving up (like pm2 with node)?

Comment: It said `Cannot allocate memory`. Did you try giving it more RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An inability to allocate *shared* memory is a special kind of beast.  It doesn't mean that the system as a whole is out of memory, but instead that you've hit one of the limits that govern shared memory allocation.

The two relevant sysctls are `kernel.shmmax` (which is the limit, in bytes, on how large a single shared memory segment can be) and `kernel.shmall` (which is the total amount of shared memory, in bytes, that can be allocated to the system). Use `grep Shmem /proc/meminfo; cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall` to visualize these amounts.

You can tell whether `shmall` has been hit by comparing the `Shmem` line of `/proc/meminfo` against `/proc/sys/kernel/shmall`.  If they're about equal, then you've hit the system-wide shared memory limit, and will need to increase `kernel.shmall` (or stop something that's got shared memory in use).  Otherwise, you'll probably need to increase `kernel.shmmax` to something larger than whatever the process that's failing wants to use.